# For complex $z$, $|z| = 1 \implies \text{Re}\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)  = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $|z|=1$, show that: $$\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{1 - z}{1 + z}\right) = 0$$

I reasoned that for $z = x + iy$, $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 1\implies x^2 + y ^2 = 1$ and figured the real part would be:

$$\frac{1 - x}{1 + x}$$

I tried a number of manipulations of the equation but couldn't seem to arrive at any point where I could link the two to show that the real part was = 0.

Comment: write $z=re^{i\theta}$ and observe that $r=1$ and $e^{i\theta} = cos \theta + i sin \theta$. Now manipulate the given condition.

Comment: You can not calculate the real part like that (see anon's answer/comment below).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easy method to do this kind of exercise is to notice that $Re(z)=0$ if and only if $z=-\overline z$. Notice that if $|z|=1$ then $\overline z=\frac{1}{z}$.

In your case 
$$ \overline{\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)}=\frac{1-\overline z}{1+\overline z}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{z}}{1+\frac{1}{z}}=\frac{z-1}{1+z}=-\frac{1-z}{1+z}$$

Usually, the replacement of the algebraic form $z=x+iy$ makes things much more complicated in problems like this. First you should try applying the standard results from the general case, such as $|z|^2=z\overline z$, or $z \in \Bbb{R}$ if and only if $z=\overline z$, etc.

Answer (score 12):

Let $z=a+bi$, where $a^2+b^2=1$ and $z\neq -1$. Then $$\begin{eqnarray}
\Re\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)
&=&\Re\left(\frac{(1-z)\overline{(1+z)}}{|1+z|^2}\right)\\
&=&\Re\left(\frac{(1-a-bi)(1+a-bi)}{(a+1)^2+b^2}\right)\\
&=&\Re\left(\frac{1-(a^2+b^2)-2bi}{(a+1)^2+b^2}\right)\\
&=&\Re\left(\frac{-2bi}{(a+1)^2+b^2}\right)=0\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 8):

Using polar form of a complex number, $z=e^{i\theta},\quad\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

Hence $\frac{1-z}{1+z}=\dfrac{1-e^{i\theta}}{1+e^{i\theta}}=\dfrac{e^{-\frac{i\theta}{2}}-e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}}{e^{-\frac{i\theta}{2}}+e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}}=\dfrac{-2i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}=-i\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$

Comment: How did you get from term 2 to 3 and from term 3 to 4?

Comment: @stariz77 Multiplying numerator and denominator by $e^{-\frac{i\theta}{2}}$ and then using the formula $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$.

Answer (score 7):

Since we are adding multiple proofs, here are two more.

**1) Geometric proof.**

[image]

$\displaystyle z$ corresponds to point $\displaystyle B$. $\displaystyle 1+z$ corresponds to $\displaystyle H$ and $\displaystyle 1-z$ to $\displaystyle G$.

$\displaystyle ACGD$ and $\displaystyle ADHB$ are rhombii, with $CD$ parallel to $\displaystyle AH$. In rhombii the diagonals intersect at right angles, and so $\displaystyle AG$ is perpendicular to $\displaystyle AH$.

Thus $\displaystyle \frac{1-z}{1+z} = ci$ for some $\displaystyle c$.

**2) Using vectors.**

We refer to the above figure.

$\displaystyle H = (1+\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$.

$\displaystyle G = (1- \cos \theta, -\sin \theta)$.

Their dot product = $\displaystyle  (1 + \cos \theta)(1- \cos \theta) - \sin^2 \theta = 1 - \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta = 0$

So $\displaystyle \vec{AH}$ and $\displaystyle \vec{AG}$ are perpendicular.

Incidentally, the converse is also true:

If $\displaystyle \text{Re}\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)  = 0$, then $\displaystyle |z| = 1$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $\: $ *Realizing* the denominator produces a purely imaginary numerator, i.e.

$$\displaystyle\ z\bar z\: =\: 1\ \:\Rightarrow\:\ \frac{(1-z)\:(1+\bar z)}{(1+z)\:(1+\bar z)}\: =\: \frac{\bar z-z}{|1+z|^2}\: =\: \frac{r\:i}{s},\ \ r,s\in \mathbb R$$

**Note** $\ $  This is  an instance of the powerful method of [rationalizing denominators](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26097/242) to simplify arithmetic of algebraic numbers or functions. Generally, $\rm F$-rationalize means coerce to an element of the base ring $\rm F$ of an algebraic extension, which classically is $\mathbb Q = $ rationals. Above we have the base ring  $\rm F =\mathbb R\subset \mathbb R[{\it i}] = \mathbb C,\:$ so rationalize means realize.

Answer (score 3):

I want to point out that the problem in your approach is that, generally,

$$\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right) \ne \frac{1-\mathrm{Re}(z)}{1+\mathrm{Re}(z)}.$$

In other words, just because there's a Re on the left of the equation doesn't mean you can replace a complex variable $z$ with its real part $x$; that's tantamount to switching the order of evaluation of two functions composed (as in $f\circ g$ vs. $g\circ f$, here with $f=\mathrm{Re}$ and $g(z)=\frac{1-z}{1+z}$).

The general approach you want to take is replacing $z$ with $x+yi$, then trying to get the whole thing inside the real part in the form $\text{blah}_1+\text{blah}_2i$, where both $\text{blah}$s are entirely real, so you can just chop off $\text{blah}_2$ to finish evaluating. Frequently this process involves slapping the conjugate $x-yi$ in there somewhere to make things real.

Comment: Not feeling *foo* and *bar* today?

Answer (score 3):

Yet another approach, is to note that $Re(\overline z_1z_2)=z_1 \cdot z_2$, where $\cdot$ denotes the euclidean dot product in $R^2$.

Let $z=x+iy$ for $x,y$ in $R$, then we have $Re(\frac{1-z}{1+z})=\overline{1-z}{\frac{1}{1+z}}=(1-x,y)\cdot (\frac{1+x}{1+2x+x^2+y^2},\frac{-y}{1+2x+x^2+y^2})=\frac{1-(x^2+y^2)}{2+2x}=0$

Comment: Re$(\bar i\bar i)=-1$ but $i\cdot i=1$ if I read you correctly. And $\overline{\frac1{1+z}}$ is proportional to $(1+x,y)$, not $(1+x,-y)$.

Comment: oh, you are right. I think it is fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. The map $$T:z\mapsto \frac{1-z}{1+z}$$ is a [Möbius transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).
2. It is well known that Möbius transforms maps circles into straight lines or circles.
3. By 1 and 2  it is sufficient to check the image of three points in order to decide the image of $\{z:\,|z|=1\}$.

Now,
$$T(1)= 0$$
$$T(-1)= \infty$$
$$T(i)=\frac{1-i}{1+i}= \frac{(1-i)\overline{(1+i)}}{|1+i|^2}=\frac{(1-i)^2}{2} = \frac{-2i}{2}=-i$$
That is the image of the unit circle is the imaginary axis and in particular 
$$\Re\frac{1-z}{1+z}=0, \qquad \text{when $|z|=1$}$$

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as many other approaches, but one I thought I'd try out:

Taking the ratio $ \ \frac{1 - z}{1 + z } \ = \ w \ = \ \zeta + i·\eta  \ $ to be equal to *some* complex number, we may arrange the equation into $ \ [ \ 1 - (\cos \theta + i·\sin \theta) \ ] \ = \ [ \ 1 + (\cos \theta + i·\sin \theta) \ ] · (\zeta + i·\eta) \ \ , \ \ z \neq -1 \ \ , $ writing $ \ z \ $ in "polar form" for $ \ |z| = 1 \ \ . $ Multiplying out the right side and equating real and imaginary parts produces the system of equations
$$  1   -   \cos \theta  \ \ = \ \ \zeta·\cos \theta \ + \ \zeta \ - \ \eta·\sin \theta \ \ \ , \ \ \ -\sin \theta \ \ = \ \ \eta·\cos \theta \ + \ \eta \ + \ \zeta·\sin \theta  $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ (1 + \zeta)·\cos \theta \ - \ \eta·\sin \theta \ \ = \ \ 1  -  \zeta \ \ \ , \ \ \ \eta·\cos \theta \ + \ (1 + \zeta)·\sin \theta \ \ = \ \ -\eta \ \ .   $$
We solve these to obtain
$$ \cos \theta \ \ = \ \ \frac{ (1 + \zeta)·(1 - \zeta) \ - \ \eta^2}{(1 + \zeta)^2 \ + \ \eta^2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{  1 \ - \ \zeta^2 \ - \ \eta^2}{(1 + \zeta)^2 \ + \ \eta^2}  \ \ ,      $$
$$ \sin \theta \ \ = \ \ \frac{  -\eta·(1 + \zeta) \ - \ \eta·(1 - \zeta)}{(1 + \zeta)^2 \ + \ \eta^2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{  -2·\eta }{(1 + \zeta)^2 \ + \ \eta^2}  \ \ .      $$
The sum of the squares of these expressions is
$$ \cos^2 \theta \ + \ \sin^2 \theta \ \ = \ \ \frac{ (1 \ - \ \zeta^2 \ - \ \eta^2)^2 \ + \ ( -2·\eta)^2 }{[ \ (1 + \zeta)^2 \ + \ \eta^2 \ ]^2} $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{  \zeta^4 \ + \ 2·\zeta^2·\eta^2 \ + \ \eta^4  \  - \  2·  \zeta^2 \ - \ 2·\eta^2  \   +  \ 1 }{[ \ ( \zeta + 1)^2 \ + \ \eta^2 \ ]^2}   $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{ [ \ ( \zeta + 1)^2 \ + \ \eta^2 \ ]·[ \ ( \zeta - 1)^2 \ + \ \eta^2 \ ]}{[ \ (\zeta + 1)^2 \ + \ \eta^2 \ ]^2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{  ( \zeta - 1)^2 \ + \ \eta^2 }{ (\zeta + 1)^2 \ + \ \eta^2 } \ \ , $$
which is only equal to $ \ 1 \ $ for all values of $ \ \theta \ $ when $ \ \zeta  =  0 \ \  . $  (We can verify that this becomes a constant function by calculating
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} \ \left[ \ \frac{  ( \zeta - 1)^2 \ + \ \eta^2 }{ (\zeta + 1)^2 \ + \ \eta^2 } \ \right]_{\zeta = 0} \ \ = \ \    \frac{  8 \ · \zeta  \ · \ \eta }{[ \ (\zeta + 1)^2 \ + \ \eta^2 \ ]^2} | _{\zeta = 0}   \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . \ \ )  $$
Hence, $ \ w \  $ is purely imaginary.

[I believe that the converse of the proposition is shown to be true by the relation for $ \ \cos^2 \theta \ + \ \sin^2 \theta \ \ . \ ] $