# $F:= \{ a+b\sqrt{7} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ closed under addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division

Tags: field-theory

I am in my math class and I came across this problem on my past midterm. How can we prove that $F:=\{ a+b\sqrt{7} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \} $ is closed under addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division by a nonzero number in the set?

Comment: Do you really not see how to prove that if you add, subtract, or multiply two numbers, each of the form $a+b\sqrt7$, you get a number of the form $a+b\sqrt7$?

Comment: i have trouble proving stuff, it is my only weakness in math. Im sorry. Like i understand what were given but i get confused of what i should use for a and b should i just say a is the for of m/n? and b is the form of p/q? or something like that. If you could guide me I would be thankful

Comment: You don't need to put anything for the form of $a$ and $b$. All you need to know about $a$ and $b$ is that they are rational, and that the sum, difference, product, and quotient of two rationals are rational (excepting division by zero), and presumably at this stage you are allowed to state that much as a fact without proving it, and then use it to prove what you are being asked to prove.

Comment: If the first three aren't pretty easy for you, you may have missed something.  Do those by just adding, subtracting, or multiplying, then doing routine simplifications.  For example (and I've actually see this happen) if you don't know that $\sqrt{7}\cdot\sqrt{7}=7$, you won't be able to figure this out, but you shouldn't be trying problems like this before you know that.  The fourth one, if you've never seen the technique before, is not so routine.

Comment: thank you so much for this guys. I appreciate for your help. really

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\Bbb Q$ is closed under addition, subtraction, and multiplication, then it shouldn't be hard to prove that $F$ is closed under those, as well. For division, do you know how to "rationalize" a denominator?

Since you know how to rationalize a denominator, then take any $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Q$ so that $c+d\sqrt{7}\neq 0$. That is, we need $c,d$ not both zero. Note that this means that $c-d\sqrt{7}\neq 0$, as well. (Why?) Hence, we have $$\begin{align}\frac{a+b\sqrt{7}}{c+d\sqrt{7}} &= \frac{a+b\sqrt{7}}{c+d\sqrt{7}}\cdot\frac{c-d\sqrt{7}}{c-d\sqrt{7}}\\ &= \frac{(ac-7bd)+(bc-ad)\sqrt{7}}{c^2-7d^2}\\ &= \frac{ac-7bd}{c^2-7d^2}+\frac{bc-ad}{c^2-7d^2}\sqrt{7}.\end{align}$$ All you need to do is justify why those two fractions in the last lines are rational, and why $c-d\sqrt{7}\neq 0$ when $c,d\in\Bbb Q$ not both zero.

For that last part, try showing for a rational number $p$ and an irrational number $\alpha$, we have $p\cdot\alpha\in\Bbb Q$ if and only if $p=0$. Then, show that $\sqrt{7}$ is not rational.

Comment: yes i know how to rationalize. But I am confused on what i should put in for a and b

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cameron. I really wish I could vote up.

Comment: You'll be able to vote up as soon as you have at least $15$ reputation. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The only somewhat tricky one is division. Let $x=a+b\sqrt{7}$, where $a+b\sqrt{7}\ne 0$. Note that $a-b\sqrt{7}\ne 0$, since $\sqrt{7}$ is irrational. (This needs proof.)
Then 
$$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{a-b\sqrt{7}}{(a-b\sqrt{7})(a+b\sqrt{7})}=\frac{a}{a^2-7b^2}+\frac{-b}{a^2-7b^2}\sqrt{7}.$$

**Remark:** To show that if $a$ and $b$ are not both $0$, then $a-b\sqrt{7}\ne 0$, maybe proceed as follows. Suppose to the contrary that $a-b\sqrt{7}=0$. By multiplying through by a suitable non-zero integer if necessary, we can assume that $a$ and $b$ are integers. We can also assume without loss of generality that the integers $a$ and $b$ have no common factor $\gt 1$. We obtain $a=b\sqrt{7}$, and therefore $a^2=7b^2$, Then $7$ divides $a^2$, but since $7$ is prime, $7$ divides $a$. Thus $a=7c$ for some $c$, and therefore $7c^2=b^2$. It follows that $7$ divides $b$, contradicting the fact that $a$ and $b$ have no common factor greater than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

To do multiplication, given two numbers in the set with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Q, (a+b\sqrt 7)(c+d\sqrt 7)=ad+7bd+(ad+bc)\sqrt 7\in \mathbb F$
The others are similar.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that division is "similar" to the above.

Comment: @MichaelHardy:  it does take rationalizing the denominator, as André Nicolas shows.  I wanted to leave the hardest one.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ For division,  $\rm\,\ 0\,\ne\,\alpha\alpha' =\, n\in \Bbb Z\ $ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\  \dfrac{\beta}\alpha = \dfrac{\alpha'\beta}{\alpha'\alpha} = \dfrac{\alpha'\beta}n$

This is called [rationalizing the denominator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+rationalizing+denominator) It works because irrational algebraic number has a rational multiple (its norm). So we can  reduce division by an irrational to division by a rational.

Here's an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118934/242) of *realizing* the denominator to prove that the real part is zero:

$$\displaystyle\ z\bar z\: =\: 1\ \:\Rightarrow\:\ \frac{(1-z)\:(1+\bar z)}{(1+z)\:(1+\bar z)}\: =\: \frac{\bar z-z}{|1+z|^2}\: =\: \frac{r\:i}{s},\ \ r,s\in \mathbb R$$

Generally, rationalizing denominators allows one to lift "existence of inverses of elements $\ne 0\:$" from a base field (e.g. $\mathbb R$) to an algebraic extension field (e.g. $\mathbb  C$). Namely, since $\mathbb R$ is a field, $\rm\ 0\ne r\in \mathbb R\ \Rightarrow\ r^{-1}\in \mathbb R\:,\:$ so

$$\rm 0\ne\alpha\in\mathbb C\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ 0\ne\alpha\alpha' = r\in \mathbb R\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \frac{1}\alpha\ =\ \frac{\alpha'}{\alpha\:\alpha'}\ = \frac{\alpha'}r\in\mathbb C $$

Thus $\:$ field $\mathbb R\ \Rightarrow\:\: $ field $\mathbb C\ $ by using the norm $\rm\:\alpha\to\alpha\ \alpha'\:$ to lift existence of inverses from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C\:.$ See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100201/242) for more.