# Is the subset $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]:=\{x+\sqrt{2}y\mid x,y\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, field-theory

Consider the subset $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]:=\{x+\sqrt{2}y\mid x,y\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$, together with the addition and multiplication usual/common in $\mathbb{R}$

> **(Does this mean that the operations $(+)$ and $(\cdot)$ are from $\mathbb{R}$ ?)**.

Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a field? Prove your testimony.

If you want to find a neutral element $e$ for multiplication, such that $e\circ x=x$, you will get stuck:

\begin{align}
e\circ x&=x\\
(x+y\sqrt2)\cdot(z+w\sqrt2)&=z+w\sqrt2\\
e=(x+y\sqrt2)&=1\qquad\qquad \forall x\neq0
\end{align}

If you want to find an inverse element for multiplication $a^{-1}$ such that $a\circ a^{-1}=e$, you will get stuck:
\begin{align}
(a+\sqrt2b)\cdot a^{-1}&=1\\
a^{-1}&=\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt2} \qquad\qquad\forall a\neq0
\end{align}
Is this the point where I can say, that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]$ is not a field, because you can't find a neutral and inverse element for all elements in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: What if you try rationalising the denominator? Also, see [Show that the set $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] = \{a + b \sqrt{2} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a field with the usual multiplication and addition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754901/show-that-the-set-mathbbq-sqrt2-a-b-sqrt2-mid-a-b-in-mathbb)

Comment: Re your bold part: Yes, the (usual) addition and multiplication in $\Bbb R$ shall be taken as the addition and multiplication in this set. In particular, you ought to first show that the sum and product of two numbers in this set are in this set. -- Re the other part: Compute $(1+\sqrt 2)(-1+\sqrt 2)$ and be surprised.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thanks!${}{}{}$

Comment: OK${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it *is* a field. A neutral element for the multiplicatio is $1\left(=1+0\sqrt2\right)$. And if $a+b\sqrt 2\neq0$, then$$\frac1{a+b\sqrt2}=\frac{a-b\sqrt2}{a^2-2b^2}=\frac a{a^2-2b^2}-\frac b{a^2-2b^2}\sqrt2\in\mathbb Q\left[\sqrt2\right].$$

Comment: The last equations prove, that if ${a+b\sqrt2\neq0}$ then$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt2}\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt2]$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.